# How can I create an array with 200 million elements on NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, macos

To do some benchmarking, I tried to create a huge array. The code was simple:

```
var hugeArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 2*1000*1000*100; i ++) {
    hugeArray.push(Math.ceil(Math.random()*100))
}
console.log(hugeArray.length);
```

After I run it with 200 million elements, I get `FATAL ERROR: invalid array length Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`. With 20 million elements, this works well, so I assume I need to change some setting.

I am using MacOS with 8 GB of RAM, if that helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

V8's heap size is limited to 1 GB..So if you want to increase it run following

`node --max-old-space-size=8000 yourScript.js`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you kindly.

Comment: No problem. Glad this helps.

Comment: Can we increase the value more? or 8000 is the limit ?

Comment: You can increase as much as your system can offer to you ...32 or 64 GB.etc.